# How can I write my own library for lcd in arduino?

Tags: arduino, lcd

I have a school assignment where I have to write my own library to work with the lcd. How can I start doing this, without using LiquidCrystal library from Arduino?

Comment: what LCD? I doubt you have to write a generic library that can handle any LCD.

Comment: @Piglet a 16x2 LCD. I have to write some generic functions like init, begin and print in Arduino.

Comment: @LibrarySystem Read the data sheet and find out what communication protocol your LCD module supports.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to do it, is to download a standard library as "template".

You can download this one and edit it, or create the same files:
https://github.com/arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal

What you need is:

- keywords.txt
- library.properties
- source folder
- optional: example folder

Then you just need to put your library-class (a .h and a .cpp) files inside the source folder.

Once you copy the entire folder in the Arduino library folder (UserData/Arduino/Libraries/), the IDE will find it automatically. You just need to include the header file of your new project (or example project).

Comment: yes, but that is just copy pasting the Arduino library. I want to access the Arduino registers and to program them to display text on LCD.

Comment: Arduino registers? You don't need to write in assembler on Arduino, for a simple library like LCD-displays. 90% of your work is to understand how the  hd44780 (display controller) works. Once you read the datasheet, you just have to implement it in your library. A simple library (begin, init and print) is not more than 100-150 lines of code. The LCD display is sooooo slow, that you can just set any output on your Arduino, without any optimisations.